# How to create Grouped Bar Chart in Vegalite?

Tags: charts, vega-lite

```
Name | Value 1 | Value 2
BTC  | 1       | 2
ETH  | 1       | 2
```

to this:
[image]

Tried to used this as an example: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_grouped.html,
but I can't make it work.

Can someone please point me to the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieved in the provided example ? Can you please add more details in your question ?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I already added the image. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using column provided in your question, You can simply use layers and keep the x axis as common and provide value1 and value2 in y axis of each layer respectively and simply provide some offset to show it as a grouped bar chart. Below is the basic spec configuration and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiiA6mBZoIACyAJ52MA7BLsr0aABMAAzpSv6BaKDESIIMamgA2qCySAhwEQBCACoAEsEFRXAAjGkAHEqtxalpACxKFmRwssr1dOHofR0gAL4KFVU16ACiTS2FxZ2oYmK9O3ADqKmHIKPjk9NrIHMDCwC6SyDjUGzKNLJkeSAAHn8AGY0OCCZQRSrVYKYaI4O6yNgIb6FYJIf40CB-QRITyCfQ-GbpBYkkZIaJwdRlUDIdQAaz+sPhEWsVKU-wA8kCgRA4Jg0PwMkoTAAvNYAZiyIA+gjYVPQEDp0SYbUWSnen2+v1QoGiwNB4Iic06SiZdwAjgwkLJQgEaKQ0RisTqQrc0LIGIJBKaaFA6c6gYVeSTSTSbAyXWaWTZgqKJVLOdzefzUO0etK2LL5SA5daxmq3rIPl8fn89S6QWCIbNjgNTXCLVabXQ7Q6lOjMYy3agPV6fX6A0G4CGlmH6YyGxFMHB-vzXhqS9rQCCvfqqxErhMpmEasKoIU1qB1Hm1qUQIrorVVUpcz8ai8RuRrl2d+7Pd7z9EEExM-VJwrLRsXcc00cYUxAH9sCRRYQxeIA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "title": "My chart",
  "width": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"name": "BTH", "value1": 28, "value2": 24, "legendTitle": "value1"},
      {"name": "ETH", "value1": 55, "value2": 25, "legendTitle": "value2"}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": -20, "size": 30, "color": "skyblue"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "value1",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": null, "ticks": false}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "size": 30, "xOffset": 18, "color": "orange"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "value2",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": null, "ticks": false}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text"},
      "encoding": {
        "fill": {
          "field": "legendTitle",
          "scale": {"range": ["skyBlue", "orange"]},
          "legend": {"title": null, "symbolType": "square", "orient": "bottom"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Is there a way to add a legend and label to this? I tried adding text mark at the bottom of the layer but it doesn't go to the top of the bar.

Comment: Edited my answer, you will need to add another field in data to get those legend labels

Comment: I tried the code but it creates a stacked bar chart. How to obtain the one in the original question with bars next to each other?